# Почему не компилируются дробные константы с точкой в конце?

Tags: c#, дизайн-языка

Внезапно обнаружил, что такой код не компилируется: https://ideone.com/KrX8T3

```
public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    double x = 1.;
  }
}
```

> prog.cs(5,17): error CS1001: Unexpected symbol `;', expecting identifier

Получается, C# хочет полную запись дробного числа `1.0`, а сокращённая `1.` его не устраивает, хотя в других языках так можно. С чем связано столь странное решение? Причём, опускать лидирующий ноль разрешено и `.1` компилируется отлично.

Comment: как вариант - считает точку вызовом метода, а не дробным делителем. Плюс, в этом случае неизвестно какой тип должен быть у константы. Почему просто суффиксы не использовать вместо точки? типа `f`, `d` и других?

Comment: @Grundy, сишные привычки))) По идее тип у `1.` тот же, что и у `1.0`, т. е. `double`. Ну может и считает вызовом метода (по ошибке похоже), но зачем? Неужели так сложно было обработать эту ситуацию чтобы быть консистентным с другими языками?

Comment: А зачем? :) если суффикс удобнее? :)

Comment: Зато вот так можно: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APsD2CuBGAbApgAmKgvKgdAVgG4g===

Comment: @VladD, ага, у меня в вопросе пример с `.1` есть.

Comment: А есть ли смысл сломя голову вводить настолько примитивные синтаксические фичи чтобы потом их отменять и ломать обратную совместимость!?

Comment: @Blackmeser, а где тут обратная совместимость ломается?

Comment: @Grundy 1..2 - это по-вашему должно быть 1.2 double или [1.0 double .. 2.0 double] ?

Comment: @Blackmeser, а с каких пор `1..2` стал `1.2 double`? какие предпосылки к этому?

Comment: @Blackmeser, `x.2` - не компилируется. Поле должно быть идентификатором, а не числом, так что тут противоречия нет. Ну и range проявилось намного позже языка - весьма маловероятно, что про него думали тогда. А ели думали, то это как раз и есть ответ на мой вопрос, только надо подтверждение найти.

Comment: А у чисел бывают члены? Интересненько так.

Comment: @ТарасАтавин, методы бывают. Например, `1.ToString()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот почему:

```
double x = 1;
string y = 1.ToString();
```

После 1. компилятор ожидает метод.
В C# предопределенные типы не настолько примитивны, как в Си.

> C# provides a set of predefined struct types called the simple types.

> C# has a unified type system. All C# types, including primitive types such as int and double, inherit from a single root object type.

> Just as these predefined types are structs, it is also possible to use structs and operator overloading to implement new “primitive” types in the C# language.

Comment: +1, но: чем плохо было бы `1..ToString()`? Это конфликтует с range (наверное), но в первой версии C# их же не было?

Comment: @VladD - `1..` - так уже `Range` получается. Продолжаем: чем плохо `1...`? :)

Comment: А что мешает ожидать метод или пустоту?

Comment: @VladD, наверное, решили, что это неочевидно смотрится. К тому же в C#, в отличие от js, есть int и double, так что надо `1.DoSmth()` - метод int'а, а `1..DoSmth()` - double'а.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, C# 1 до Range как средневековью до высадки на Луне.

Comment: @Qwertiy была бы неоднозначность в понимании, что делает точка после единицы тогда. Даже если с точки зрения компилятора замена роли точки на лету возможна, то для некоторых разработчиков это бы добавило больше путаницы. Хотя, честно говоря вещественные литералы настолько редко используются, что я бы мог их с четырьмя точками писать. Возможность писать эти литералы без ноля ничего мне не даст. Реально не вижу необходимости в этом.

Comment: @aepot, чтоб было как у всех (Си, JS, Java, вроде даже VB и Паскаль).

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда можно завести инмпрув в dotnet/roslyn на гитхабе, по идее.